# Greendao: nested entities and relationships

Tags: android, sqlite, entity, greendao

So I have this scenario:

There is entity `Post` which has a nested `Author` entity. This is a Many-to-one relationship as multiple`Post`'s can be created by a single `Author`.

```
public class Post{
@Id
long id;

long authorId;
@ToOne(joinProperty = "authorId")
Author author;
}

public class Author{
@Id
long id;
//This is useless for greendao. I have it here because it flows from the REST endpoint.
long postId;
}
```

When I get my response from the REST endpoint, the Post entity is pulled along with the Author entity. The `authorId` in Post entity does not flows from the REST endpoint.

**Question**

- When I persist the `Post` entity to the sqlite DB, only fields of `Post` entity are pushed. The Author entity is not pushed. I tried setting the `authorId` on the `Post` entity but without any luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem. Looks like GreenDao cant insert inner objects in tables automaticaly. You need insert Author manualy in Author table through authorDao.